# How a serverless function be faster than a normal endpoint called to a server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, serverless-framework

As per my limited knowledge, 
A serverless function (Ex: Firebase Cloud Function) execute the whole code per invocation. It might include loading dependencies, 3rd party modules, setting up database connections and tearing them down etc. that take a lot of time.
In a traditional server, all the dependencies are loaded, database connections are cached and reused.

Therefore how does a serverless function work faster than a typical server call?

Comment: In the real world, functions are not faster than virtual machines. Functions run in containers, which is a form of virtualization. These containers need to be loaded (called cold start), scheduled and then run. They are not faster than a correctly sized virtual machine. The key benefits are scaling, economy and usually improved DevOps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "serverless" function is nothing but just a normal server (perhaps a container) with all the normal dependencies & stuff being loaded on-demand.

So a server is created when you make an API call (therefore saving you money when you're not getting those API calls). Now once one of these server (containers) are created, you might keep it around for a while to let it handle some more API calls as time goes on. When the traffic to your server goes down, you can kill it to save cost.

So you can imagine ending up is a scenario where the first API call you make takes a lot of time ("cold-start") & then subsequent requests are fast (since everything is already setup).

Now depending on the amount of resources given to these "on-demand servers" - they can be faster than something more traditional. I would also guess that since these are first class offerings by cloud providers, their implementation is more optimized than other services which may be doing the same thing (like how RDS is faster than a database running on EC2).

So **on average** you may see your serverless function performing faster. Of course there is always that "cold-start" issue which may be problematic for you.

Of course there are other advantages & disadvantages as well:

- Pro: No infrastructure to maintain
- Pro: Seamless integration with other cloud services
- Con: Vendor lock-in

Answer (score 1):

Its more a misconception that it is quicker, a FaaS (function as a service) is simply a single function being executed when it is invoked. If you had unlimited server capacity executing a very simple function it would also be fast.

However Serverless benefits from the following:

- Generally cheaper (only pay for what you use, no idle time)
- Unlimited resource immediately (no waiting to scale up or down to meet demand).
- Simpler to decouple components, it can only do one thing.
- No overhead for your team managing patching and security, this is all handled for you.

People love serverless because they can turn their idea to a POC in a quick period of time without having to really think about resource requirements.